# How to redirect my homepage installed in a sub-directory to another sub-directory?

Tags: redirects, homepage

I have a Joomla website which has been installed in a sub-directory named "joomla" and has pages like the following structures:

```
http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php
http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/1391-09-23-16-04-58
http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/1388-06-28-13-55-06/214-thumbnailsinlofinxepersian
http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/about-us
```

Now I'd like to redirect the homepage **only** to the new Wordpress version of the website, `http://parsilatex.com/site/`. In other words, I'd just like to redirect the old homepage to the new one. When I use the code below, I get "Page not found" errors.

```
 Redirect 301 /joomla/index.php http://www.parsilatex.com/site/
```

**How can I accomplish this via my .htaccess file?**

Comment: Try removing the `/` from the `/joomla/index.php` so it is `joomla/index.php`. I'm not sure if it works but it's worth trying :)

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you still want requests that look like:

```
http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/1391-09-23-16-04-58
```

...to still work. If this is not the case, please leave a comment and I will update the answer.

I have not tested this here, but try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} $/joomla/index\.php^ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.parsilatex.com/site/ [R,L]
```

... my examples that I keep for just this reason have the leading `/` in `$/joomla/index.php^`, you can try it without the leading `/` like this `$joomla/index.php^`.

... and this may work too...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule $/joomla/index\.php^ http://www.parsilatex.com/site/ [R,L]
```

... and again try it with or without the leading `/`...

...and see if this gives you what you want. If not, please leave a comment and I will try again.

Comment: Yes. That's the case, but when I use your code in my `.htaccess` file located in my `public_html` folder, I see no changes.

Comment: @Vahid Damanafshan I updated the answer. Let's see if these work. I am here the rest of the evening unless I go to get ice cream.

Comment: Thanks again, but your new updated answer doesn't work, as well:-(

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Huh. I have to think on this a bit. It is obviously something stupid/simple that I am missing. We are close.

Comment: Ok, so I'm awaiting your solution:-)

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Do you have RewriteEngine On in your .htaccess file at or near the top? I could not think of anything except this.

Comment: Yes, I have `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan I would have expected the above to work fine, but because we are having trouble, I used my live server to test. I tested the first solution and what I found was that it seemed to work as you expect without the ^ and $ which brackets the regular expression. I would have thought that would be fine, but my testing suggests testing the first solution without the ^ and $. Try that and let me know what you get. Meanwhile, I will leave the test scenario on my server for now.

Comment: I tested what you said, but it redirects not only the old homepage, but also every other links from the old website to the new homepage. In other words, by entering every link from the old website in the browser, it goes to the new homepage.

Comment: Okay. Back to the drawing board. We are close.

Comment: I was concerned about removing the ^ and $ which should have worked. Of course something was standing in the way. I edited the first example and escaped the . [dot] in the index.php and it works okay here. Can you try that WITH the ^ and $ and the \ to escape the . [dot]?

Comment: The only change I see is that links with structures like `http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/about-us` goes to 404 error page.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Does http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php go to www.parsilatex.com/site/ at least?

Comment: I retrieve my previous comment: I see no changes.

Comment: "Does parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php go to www.parsilatex.com/site/ at least?": No:-(

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan *RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} $/joomla/index\.php^ [NC]* should work to redirect to /site/ at least. When I test this here, it works. When I add /*anything* at the end, this rule is ignored and is processed normally. I experimented with %{QUERY_STRING} but that requires a ? Are there any other .htaccess code before this that maybe gets in the way. Try moving to the top of .htaccess just under RewriteEngine On.

Comment: "Are there any other .htaccess code before this that maybe gets in the way?" No, but I found the solution! I'll post it as an answer. Thank you for your patience and efforts.

Comment: No No! The solution I found, didn't work. It was a browser cache! In fact when I use `RewriteRule ^joomla/$ http://parsilatex.com/site/index.php [R=301,L]`http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla go to www.parsilatex.com/site, but http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php doesn't.